# memmove resulting in growing heap size and eventual termination

Tags: c

I am trying to read and process a binary file. Due to the way its written, I read it in a char array. After I have processed the data. I move the remaining data to the begining of the char buffer to avoid the buffer overflow. I am using memmove for this but this seems to be causing a heap growth which shows my memory utilization increasing until the process is killed. What I was trying to achieve was a circular array so that i don't have to use too much memory.

```
char readDat[5000000];
char* readBuf = readDat;
while(reading file)
{
     processData(readBuf);
     memmove(readBuf, readBuf + processedSize, totalSize - processedSize);
}
```

Because of other dependencies I would like to do this using char arrays only rather than using other structures like queue or lists.

Comment: There is no heap usage shown here. Most likely explanation is that processData is leaking.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was processData. Since memmove was new to me, I was thinking that could be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memmove` doesn't allocate memory. That means either:

1. You move more memory than you expect and overwrite pointers and sizes that the heap management code uses to calculate the heap size. That would be a very lucky strike but maybe look at the values of the involved variables and double check them.
2. The error is elsewhere, probably in `processData()` or even outside of the code that you show us.